Best way to host a manually crafted openapi.yaml spec in Spring
Looking around for this answer I have only found how to generate and host the openapi spec from code, rather than the other way around.
We have created a .yaml file with all of our api specs in it. We use that to generate some code with stubs for implementation. Now we want to host a swagger endpoint that serves the swagger resources with the .yaml file we are using to generate the implementation
I have had some success by copying the swagger resources into a folder and serving that as static resources, referencing the yaml as another static resource endpoint. This feels janky and unstable and it seems there must be a standard way to do this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Have not seen a recommended way to do this.

As a swagger developer in these times, I can tell you are not doing it so janky. Don't worry because Swagger uses it as a static resource too and publish it as a Node.js server as you know. If you insist it more clear, you can use Git on it and clone when open it. You can use easy script or add a few lines of code on source server code on Swagger. Good luck :)
